# How to make array empty if no values present in php?

Tags: php

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ratio] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ratio] => 
        )

)
```

This is the array coming while posting data. I want to make this array null i.e. array().  how i can i make it if no values are present ?

Comment: use an if statement to check if the array is empty if it is then create a new empty array

Comment: Use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to apply [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to each embedded array. Then maybe use `array_filter()` again on the outer array, to remove the emptied arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove all inner "empty" arrays, map an `array_filter` across the array:

```
array_map('array_filter', $arr)
```

```
→ [[], []]
```

To remove those empty arrays completely, `array_filter` that result:

```
$arr = [['ratio' => null], ['ratio' => null]];
$result = array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $arr));
```

```
→ []
```